# The slope of $nx\ \%\ m$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

*(This is a follow-up question to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090706/the-slope-of-nx-m) I asked at MSE. I edited due to an important hint from Will Sawin - see his comments below.)*

---

There will be this question at the end of this post:

> - Prove that the slope of $nx\ \%\ m$ (as defined below) equals $n$ for all $n,m$.

But let's start gently.

---

Let $x\ \%\ m$ be the residue of $x$ modulo $m$, i.e.

$$x \equiv x\ \%\ m\pmod{m}$$

Let $\mu^n_m$ denote "multiplication by $n$ modulo $m$", i.e.

$$\mu^n_m(x) = nx\ \%\ m$$

---

Plotting $\mu^n_m$ for $0 < n < m$ yields patterns with characteristic "slopes", here for $m=64$:

[image]
<sub>[click image to enlarge]</sub>

---

I was looking for a sensible definition of the slope of $\mu^n_m$ and came up with the following definition:

Let $k$ be the smallest number greater than $1$ which minimizes $(k - 1)^2 + (\mu^n_m(k) - n)^2$.

Let $C^n_m(s)$ be the "slope condition" defined by

$$C^n_m(s) \equiv ((k - 1)s - \mu^n_m(k) + n) \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$$

which can be written with tongue in cheek as

$$s \equiv (\mu^n_m(k) - n)/(k - 1)\pmod{m},$$

Let then the slope $s(n,m)$ of $\mu^n_m$ be the number defined by

$$s(n,m)=
\begin{cases}
s & \text{if } s \text{ is the unique } s \text{ with } C^n_m(s)\\
n & \text{if there is no unique } s \text{ with } C^n_m(s) \text{, but } C^n_m(n) \\
s_0 & \text{ otherwise, with } s_0 \text{ the smallest } s \text{ with } C^n_m(s) \\
\end{cases}$$

I've chosen this definition for two reasons:

1. Part 1 (the definition of $k$) considers the fact, that the dominant lines in the plot of $\mu^n_m$ (which "visualize" the slope of the pattern) are those with a minimal number of parallels, i.e. a maximal distance between parallels, and thus the highest number of points on them, i.e. a minimal distance of points on them. So $k$ directly yields the "visual" slope.
2. You can apply the same definition for the non-modular case: the number $k>1$ that minimizes $(k - 1)^2 + (n\cdot k - n)^2 = (k - 1)^2(1 + n^2)$ is always $2$ – independently of $n$ –, and the slope is accordingly $(n\cdot k - n)/(k - 1) = n$.

---

To see the effect of non-unique $s$ fulfilling the slope condition $C^n_m(s)$, here are the minimal slopes $s$ for $m = 64$, i.e. the minimal $s$ which fulfill $C^n_m(s)$ (i.e. not the $s(n,m)$ themselves!), together with the "visual" slopes of the dominant lines. The plot for $\mu^n_m$ has a shade of gray from white for $s = 0$ to black for $s = m-1$:

[image]

---

I did observe that – as far as I could see – $n$ is the unique number that fulfills the slope condition $C^n_m(n)$ if $m$ is prime, and that $n$ always fulfills the slope condition $C^n_m(n)$, and thus $s(n,m) = n$ for **all** pairs $(n,m)$. (This implies that the third case in the definition of $s(n,m)$ never occurs.)

So to prove that $s(n,m) = n$ for all $n,m$ is equivalent to prove that $C^n_m(n)$ for all $n,m$.

And so my question is:

> How to prove $C^n_m(n)$ for all $n,m$?

Comment: You can't divide by an even number modulo 64 in a unique way. This is the only source of subtlety in what you're doing.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks for this important hint! What does "the  only source of subtlety" mean? How would you suggest to reflect it in my question? Does it make my observations and the question obsolete?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. Because $\mu_m^n(n_0)=n n_0 \mod m$, in the case where division is unique we have $s_m^n = (nn_0 - n) / (n_0-1) = n$. So the slope not being $n$ in some cases is simply a consequence of division being non-unique.

Comment: @WillSawin: I edited my question. Does this reflect correctly what you said? And may the question remain "valid"?

Comment: The non-uniqueness obviously occurs when $\gcd ( (n_0-1),m) \neq 1$. So it's equivalent to ask when the $n_0$  minimizing your function is not relatively prime to $m$.

Comment: @WillSawin: I edited my question another time. Isn't it obsolete anymore, i.e. is it a "real" question now - with a non-evident answer?

Comment: 22 versions in under two days.

Comment: It's called "optical illusion"...

Comment: @WhatsUp: What do you mean? What is the illusion?

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad sense of humor... but seriously speaking this problem is perhaps too elementary for people on this site. Also, you should probably stick to $n$ coprime to $m$, and try different modulus (i.e. vary the value of $m$). This will be more systematic.

Comment: @WhatsUp: But as I believe to have found out, the answer doesn't depend on $n$ being coprime to $m$ and not on $m$ at all - that's why I didn't go the systematic (differentiating) way but asked the general question. (And is the answer really that elementary and evident, considering the definition of $k$?)

Comment: 24 versions, and counting.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I just try to optimize my question - and suppose that there are not too many readers who will even notice that there have been any edits - except when they look into the edit history. But feel free to keep on counting.

Comment: What readers notice, Hans, is that the same question keeps returning to the front page over and over and over, repeatedly pushing other questions off.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Ah, I wasn't aware of this! Sorry for that, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: I don't think this MathOverflow level, but I'm not very active here (scratches head).

Answer (score 3):

The usual equation for a line, $y=mx+c$, has gradient $m$. In your modulo case, we have:

$$y = nx \pmod m$$

with $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ as a variable, and $c=0$.

The gradient is always $n$, as we can see from this [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator):

[image: desmos mod graph instructions][image: cdesmos mod graph]

The line is translated parallel to the $y$-axis for every 'mod $3$' block encountered, without changing the slope of the line.

Your dot graphs are misleading. They make it look like the gradient is dramatically changing, but if you plotted a continuous line, you will see that the actual gradient of the line is actually getting steeper, but the individual points are getting sparser, hence the illusion.

From what I can understand from your 'slope condition' is that you are trying to find the point nearest to another point, and use these two points to define a slope, which would give you a 'visual slope'.
But then $C_m^n$ won't always be $n$.

From your definition:

$$(k - 1)^2 + (\mu^n_m(k) - n)^2$$

which provide the square of the hypotenuse of the x-distance and the y-distance's involved, the second term is largely a guess (from the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: Sorry to say, but I'm afraid that you missed the point of my question: of course you can *define* the slope of $y = nx \pmod m $ to be $n $ but my question arises from another definition, which is not totally senseless - and takes the undeniable illusion serious and partly explains it.

Comment: There will be this question at the end of this post:
Prove that the slope of nx % m(as defined below) equals n for all n,m.'?

Comment: As I've said: "as defined below".

Comment: @HansStricker; I've added a bit to help understand your 'slope condition'

Answer (score 0):

I got lost in notation, and that's why I didn't see *immediately* that $C^n_m(n)$ holds for all $n,m$ - tautologically, and independently of how $k$ was defined:

$$(k - 1)n - \mu^n_m(k) + n \equiv nk - nk\ \%\ m \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$$

because $x - x\ \%\ m \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$ by definition of $x\ \%\ m$

I have to agree with user WhatsUp and admit that "this problem is perhaps too elementary for people on this site". Sorry for that.